# Extraction SimpleXMLElement PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this file in XML:

http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=80b5e81c-c769-478a-aee7-fbe149aacfe3&apikey=cf415862-c0ac-4085-bc03-be80a26f9063&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes.xml

I would like to print the content xml tag

I've tried that:

```
<?php

$xml = 'http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=80b5e81c-c769-478a-aee7-fbe149aacfe3&apikey=cf415862-c0ac-4085-bc03-be80a26f9063&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes.xml';
$xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $xmlcont->track->title;

?>
```

but it does not work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following:

```
$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement('http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=80b5e81c-c769-478a-aee7-fbe149aacfe3&apikey=cf415862-c0ac-4085-bc03-be80a26f9063&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes.xml', NULL, TRUE);
$tracks = $xmlObj->xpath("//tracks");
if(count($tracks) > 0) {
    foreach($tracks as $track) {
        echo $track->track->title . "\n";
    }
}
```

Just set the 3rd parameter of `SimpleXMLElement` to `true` when you need to get data from URL